# Can't open page in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

Using SP 2010 and SPD 2010, I've found the problem: when I try to open page in Designer (using Site Actions -> Edit in Sharepoint Designer), it doesn't open, but there is popup window with invite to load Sharepoint Designer. But SPD is installed. How to fix it?

Comment: can you open the page from designer?

Comment: @Jesus Shelby, yes, I can.

Comment: I guess you are using Internet Explorer?

Comment: @Robert Lindgren, I used IE and Chrome.

Comment: @Robert Lindgren, thanks a lot! Sorry for duplicate question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled SPD on your Web Application in Central Administration, and have you enabled the use of SPD on the site collection your wording on, and have you at least design permission on the site you want to edit?

Reference: [Manage Permissions and Control Access to Sharepoint Designer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592376)

Comment: yes, everything is enabled, and my permisson level is farm administrator.

Comment: @MaxZhukov Is your farm admin site collection owner? If not, what privilege does your farm admin have on the site/page your trying to edit?

Comment: yes, I'm site collection owner, it's development server. I suppose that the problem isn't in permissions. Is there any binding between SP Server and SPD? Maybe my SP Server can't find designer? But I can run SPD from windows...